where are the IP ranges for lookerstudio and sheets stored?
Where are the IP ranges for both sheets and Looker Studio stored? I tried using an API to connect to Databricks, but the message of error says:

API request failed with status 403:
{"error_code":403,"message":"Source IP address: XXX

But the ip value is not one in neither the links below. Does someone know if the IP ranges are in somewhere else?

https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json
https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json

